# Does Tabris iOS client development require a Mac?

Tags: mobile

Does Tabris iOS client development require a Mac? For example - If the pre-built client is used, do we still need Macs for iOS clients?

Answer (score 0):

You only need a Mac for development, if you want to build your own iOS App from the sources.

If you don't have a Mac, you can [request a precompiled Tabris iOS App](http://developer.eclipsesource.com/tabris/downloads/request-a-build/), custom built for your iOS Device, Branding and Server URL.

So, like you said - you don't need a Mac for iOS development with Tabris.